# How does the type interface work with GORM?

Tags: go, interface, grails-orm, go-gorm, go-interface

I have an interface type named `Invoice` :

```golang
type Invoice interface {
    GetTransactions() ([]Transaction, error)
}

type DebitInvoice struct { 
    gorm.Model
    ClientID uint  `json:"client_id"`
    Client   Store `json:"client"`
    Debt     uint  `json:"debt"` //REMAINING PAYMENT
}

func (d DebitInvoice) GetTransactions() ([]Transaction, error) {
    // process
    return transactions, nil
}

type CreditInvoice struct { //PEMBELIAN
    gorm.Model
    InvoiceCreditID string `json:"invoice_credit_id"`
    StoreID         uint   `json:"store_id"`
    Store           Store  `json:"store"`
    Debt            uint   `json:"debt"` //REMAINING PAYMENT
}

func (c CreditInvoice) GetTransactions() ([]Transaction, error) {
    // process
    return transactions, nil
}
```

as you can see, the `DebitInvoice` and `CreditInvoice` are `Invoice` because it implements `GetTransactions()([]Transactions, error)`.

and I have this kind of model (in struct) where we are using `Invoice` interface as one of the field

```golang
type Transaction struct {
    gorm.Model
    InventoryID uint      `json:"inventory_id"`
    Inventory   Inventory `json:"inventory"`
    InvoiceID   uint      `json:"invoice_id"`
    InvoiceType string    `json:"invoice_type"` //Credit/Debit (Out/In)
    Invoice     Invoice   `json:"invoice"`
    TotalPrice  uint      `json:"total_price"`
    Discount    uint      `json:"discount"`
}
```

But when I migrate this with GORM AutoMigrate. It doesn't work, it shows `unsupported data type: program_akuntansi/models.Invoice` and the `transactions` table is not created

My expectations with `Transaction` model is :

- `Invoice` field will create a new record to their respective table
- `InvoiceType` field is the name of table that invoice created
- `InvoiceID` field is the ID of the record in `InvoiceType` table

but none of it doesn't work

So back to my question, how does the Interface Type work with GORM and how do I fix my code?

Comment: You can't do this. 1: Split into two models. 2: Use string type, then implement Getter, perform json decoding according to `InvoiceType` and return the specific structure. [example](https://go.dev/play/p/vd9c_F-IGmd).